# Options for broken hard drive power supply

Tags: hard-drive

I literally just bought a new hard drive and of course it breaks immediately upon plugging it in. I can't return it (I'm in a country where there is no concept of returns, especially not for imported goods)

Basically the plastic "shield" for the power connection just snapped off like paper.

What are my options? Also, what's it called, technically speaking, the part that broke?

[image]

Comment: You are probably SOL if you can't return it.  That bit of plastic on the power connector isn't something you are going to be able to replace.

Comment: Manufacterers usually have a world wide 1 year warranty.  Try taking it back to the shop or the direct approach.  e.g. for seagate.  http://www.seagate.com/au/en/support/warranty-and-replacements/

Comment: I can take it back to the store, I just know it's going to be a waste of time. (I'm in Peru, the taxes on electronic imports make it so that all electronics purchases are essentially buyer beware). I think SOL is the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is something you absolutely can't replace, you cannot get a replacement part for (you can't, really), and that you're wiling to use after a mildly silly repair, then...

Glue it. Seriously. Get some E6000 or some strong epoxy and glue the tab back to the drive. Don't coat the electrical contacts and let it sit for a good long time so you don't gas out glue garbage into your socket. Your electrical tabs aren't broken, so this should work fine. I've done it a few times at home.

Carefully insert it. Try to never replace it until it dies. With your extremely limited options, this becomes a fairly sensible solution. People probably won't like it, as there is a "replace everything" mentality in IT/IS for very good reasons.

**As a disclaimer**, don't use it to store critical data after this. You can do what you feel like you need to, but I won't recommend it. This is definitely a "home networking" level repair. If you're concerned about your data, either recycle the drive or make it into a wind chime.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to successfully get it plugged in after gluing it. But it wouldn't spin up. Looks like this is my addition to environmental waste for the year. There was nothing on it, it was brand new (all the more frustrating).

Comment: Hey, that's worlds better than it having something you wanted on it.

Comment: One other possible solution: even the best glue won't make a repair as strong as the original molded part.  You can do that to help act as a guide, but you could also glue in the cable (which would permanently attach it).  There generally isn't a lot of clearance around the connector.  Coat the outside that will be in contact with the socket wall with a thin layer of silicone adhesive.  When you push in the connector, a lot of this will be scraped off and collect above the socket.  You can shape this to contact the top of the socket and side of the connector for a little extra holding power.

Answer (score 1):

> What are my options?

This part already has been answered, recapping most:

1. Return to shop. (not applicaple in your case).
2. Return to manufacturer (it should not snap off unless you used brute force. This should work regardless of country you are in but the overhead/time spent might not be worth it.
3. Repair (as answered by SmallLoanOf1M). Esp. since the electric lines seem intact.
4. Or repair with a new connector soldered to it. A SATA extension cable is about EUR 1 (and 6 weeks shipping from China to NL). Using that you could just solder all the connectors and never worry about touching the broken&repaired part again.

Getting to the unanswered part:

> Also, what's it called, technically speaking, the part that broke?

It is the data connection for a SATA device. The wide part of the connector is for power. The smaller part for connecting the high speed SATA data cable. Any bad solder jobs might interfere with the 3 or 6Gbit/sec signaling rates..

Comment: 5. Throw it out and buy a new one. (Checkmark)